# Trouble authorizing agileware.civiquickbooks

Tags: extension, accounting

I have been trying to connect CiviCRM and QuickBooks Online using the extension from [Agilware](https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civiquickbooks). I have followed the instructions (I think) but can't get past the authorization. I have entered the production keys on the settings page, but when I click AUTHORIZE, I get the error message (from QuickBooks) "We're sorry! We're experiencing some problems. Please try again later."

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I found other people getting this message (while connecting other apps) and I wonder if my issue is the redirect URI, but it doesn't say anything about this in the instructions from Agilware. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Steve

Comment: may also be worth opening an Issue on their Github page

Comment: Yeah, I was about to. Probably wise. Thanks.

Comment: Ever fix this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried contacting QuickBooks? I have tested it and it works fine. Make sure your QB account has sufficient permissions.

Comment: I'm struggling with this also. The Readme talks about entering the Redirect URI or endpoint from the extension into the Quickbooks developer site. But this is not evident. Stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I see Steve did open an issue on their github at https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civiquickbooks/issues/3 which is now set as Closed with the response from the developers

> (AgileWare) have tested this using Australian QBO users - it works fine. This extension uses the QBO API to connect to the QBO services, I'm not aware of any specific reason as to why it "would not work in the US" - it should work